# How to parse multiple formats with Noda Time?

Tags: nodatime

I like the Noda Time handling of formatting and parsing values using the various `*Pattern` types in the `NodaTime.Text` namespace. However, user input is often not as regular as a single format.  For example, our app uses the time format `"h:mm tt"` but we would like to be able to parse user input in any of the following formats:

- `h:mm tt`
- `h:mmtt` (no space)
- `h:mm t`
- `h:mmt` (no space)
- `h tt`
- `hh:mm`
- and so on...

Is there a way to use Noda Time to parse input that may be in any of a number of formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry for taking so long to respond to this.)

Annoyingly, it looks like we haven't exposed this.

It's *present* in Noda Time in the [`CompositePattern`](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Text/Patterns/CompositePattern.cs) class. Unfortunately that's currently internal. I've raised [issue 147](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=147) to fix this at some point (probably in the 1.1 time frame).

For the moment, it's probably easiest to just use the same code from `CompositePattern` - you needn't create your own `IPattern<T>` implementation for this, as it's only really the `Parse` method which is useful. (Indeed, you could even write it as an extension method on `IEnumerable<IPattern<T>>`, although I'm not sure offhand whether we've given enough visibility to create the same kind of failure result.)